# Why can't I register on SuperUser without OpenID?

Tags: support, openid

I left the "register" window open for two days and it never completed.

How can I register without using an OpenID?

Answer (score 11):

You can select the Stack Exchange button on the left and use your email and password as a login (obviously once you create an account...).  In the background, this is a true OpenId provider, but to you, acts just like a regular username/password combo.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Well... You are registered or you would not have been able to ask a question!

It may not help you now, but for others, This site is only OpenID, but, this is a very quick and efficient process.

If you have a Google or similar account, it is just a couple of clicks and you have an account here!

To others, you can just click the new sign up link below the OpenID providers, and you can create an account, again, quite fast... but with just a bit more information!

Comment: except he's *not* registered :)

Comment: You can ask questions if you're not registered.

Comment: I guess I am not used to such a registration process (totally unknown I'd already registered since I never logged in on my first question). I prefer individual usernames and passwords per site. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I'm still not clear then on how to register. I can ask questions being unregistered and when I try to register I can't register. But I can log in to my unregistered account with  an open-ID???? I was just hoping to sign up and join the community.

Comment: @Liam - I am very confused, but, try clearing your cookies and come back to this site, then, click login and try logging in through Google or wherever you did it the first time... log in to Google or whatever page you go to and wait to be forwarded here. If you then see Your name on the title bar, you are logged in.

Comment: I used another pc. I logged on through google and I am now a new user with zero questions etc.

Comment: If I can recall on my first visit, I clicked on ask a question, submitted and got replies and all the time at the page top it shows me as Liam. Now registering through my gmail I am now called a number. How can I get to be Liam?

Comment: And I need a 5 reputation to answer my own question.

Comment: Unregistered User
name  Liam
member for  10 days

Answer (score 1):

There are [multiple OpenID providers](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/), try a few, one of them is bound to work.