# Why can't I create a superuser login? Why do I have to use a third party?

Tags: support, comments, user-accounts

Why can't I create a superuser login? Why do I have to use a third party? What are your quality standards? Why can't I comment?

Comment: You can create a "SuperUser login" at http://superuser.com/users/login#create-account

Answer (score 5):

> Why can't I create a superuser login? Why do I have to use a third party?

You *can* create a Super User login. What you'll get is an OpenID created by Stack Exchange, the owners of Super User. So this isn't really a third party option.

You can also choose third party OpenID providers such as Google, Facebook or Yahoo!

> What are your quality standards?

Explaining everything that applies here would take a while, but to summarize in a few bullet points:

- Be clear. If you're asking a question, imagine that not everyone sits in front of your computer to solve the problem for you. See [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).
- Make it relevant. Answer a question only if you can solve the problem. See [How to Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer).
- Use proper formatting and capitalization. Use a spell checker.
- Always cite your sources, and quote passages you didn't write yourself.

See also: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

> Why can't I comment?

Because [you need 50 reputation](https://superuser.com/privileges/comment) to be able to do so.

Answer (score 3):

https://superuser.com/faq has some of the answers you seek. (The last 2, to be specific.)

About openID... it's much more convenient to have one login for everything, rather than lots and lots for every site, don't you think? You can make an account on Stack Exchange, that's the closest thing to a SU account and bonus, it'll work if you get a question migrated to another SE site! See: [Why can't I register on SuperUser without OpenID?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2814/why-cant-i-register-on-superuser-without-openid/2816#2816)